# How to extract time domain information when recreating the signal by taking the inverse FFT

Tags: python, fft

I'm trying to recreate the the original signal from the FFT of a signal sample. When taking Inverse FFT, I'm only getting an amplitude information (only one column). How can I get the corresponding time coordinates?

This is a screen shot of my original signal, recorded from 0 to 10s with step 0.001s. When I take the IFFT, I'm getting the same number of data points as my signal, but can't find the corresponding time information.

[image: This is the plot of 2 signals]

How can I get the correct time information?

I'm including the Python code code I used and a plot of the 2 signals.

```
#generating signal here
import numpy as np
k = float ( 3.1416*2) 
f1 = 100
f2 = 150
f3 = 250
ds = max(f1,f2,f3)
ds = float(4*ds)
dt = 1.000/ds
lf = min (f1,f2,f3)
lT = 1.00/lf
N = 10 # cycles
totaltime = N*lT
data = []
tt = []
mf = 1/dt 
print "TotalTime =", totaltime
for t in np.arange(0.0, totaltime,dt/100 ) :
    #t = tk/mf

    print t
    wave1 = np.sin(k*f1*t)
    wave2 = np.sin(k*f2*t)
    wave3 = np.sin(k*f3*t)
    summ = wave1 + wave2 + wave3
    print t,"    ", summ
    tt.append(t)
    data.append(summ)
print tt
print data  
np.savetxt("data.txt",np.c_[tt,data])


#######################
#taking the FFT here
fourier = []
tt =[]
yy=[]

logname = str("data.txt")
with open (logname,"rb") as wdata:
        for line in wdata     :
        if not line.startswith("#") :

        sl = line.split()
        c11 = float(sl[0])
        #c11 = c1*10**(-12)
        c2 = float(sl[1])
        tt.append(c11)
        yy.append(c2)
n = len(yy)
n1 = len(tt)
print "n=",n,"(",n1,")"
#to calculate the time step , find the difference between 2 time-values
t0 = float(tt[0]) 
print "t0=",t0

t1 = float(tt[1])
print "t1=",t1
ts = t1 - t0 
print "ts=", ts
yf = numpy.fft.fft(yy)
yf_abso = numpy.abs(yf)

freq = numpy.fft.fftfreq(n,d=ts)

numpy.savetxt('fft-data.txt',numpy.c_[freq,yf_abso])

######################
# taking the inverese FFT

filename = str("fft-data.txt") 
FFTdata =[]
FREQdata = []

with open (filename,'r') as fftfile :
    for line in fftfile       :
        if not line.startswith("#") :
            split_line = line.split()
            fpoint = float(split_line[1])
            freqz  = float(split_line[0])
            FFTdata.append(fpoint)
            FREQdata.append(freqz)

ireverse = np.fft.ifft(FFTdata)
reverse  = np.abs(ireverse)
print type(reverse)  
np.savetxt ("ireverse.txt", ireverse)
np.savetxt("reverse.txt", reverse)
```

Comment: a clue which may help you is your plot clearly shows original signal wobbles above and below zero line however your synthesized output never goes negative

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks .. that fixed the amplitude part but my main problem is finding the time coordinates. Can you give me a hind on that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sample locations for the output of the IFFT are the same as those for the input to the FFT. You are doing that part right.

The output of the IFFT looks shifted, but it is not. What happens is that you threw away the phase information of the frequency spectrum when you saved it. You do

```
yf_abso = numpy.abs(yf)
```

and then save `yf_abso`. By taking the absolute value, you have thrown away important information. There is a reason that the FFT produces complex values. Throwing away half that information means you cannot reconstruct the original signal any more.

If you save the complex values, and use those in the last part of your code to compute the IFFT, then the **real component** of the output of the IFFT will match your input signal. The imaginary component there should be close to zero, different just due to numerical precision issues in floating-point computations.